# Disable AMQP integration with Sleuth

Tags: spring-cloud, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have a Java Spring-Cloud-based microservice integrated with RabbitMQ using Spring Boot Starter AMQP (extract from a `pom.xml` below):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now I would like to connect this service to the Zipkin monitoring using Sleuth. According to the [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-sleuth/1.3.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_sleuth_with_zipkin_via_rabbitmq_or_kafka), when AMQP support is enabled, Sleuth sends all its data through a RabbitMQ queue. For some reason I would like to disable this default behaviour and send data via HTTP. Probably there is one magic property which I cannot find. Do you know how I can force my application to send Sleuth-related data via HTTP to a Zipkin Server (also a Spring Boot application with `@EnableZipkinServer` annotation)?

In addition I would like to mention that after removing the AMQP support everything works fine, i.e. Zipkin receives tracing data via HTTP.

Moreover, setting both `spring.zipkin.collector.http.enabled: true` and `spring.zipkin.collector.amqp.enabled: false` (and `spring.zipkin.collector.rabbitmq.enabled: false`) does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Edgware release train, just set `spring.zipkin.sender.type=web`. That way you force the HTTP based span sending